# Ruby-on-Rails convert variable to link_to array param

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, link-to

I have a action `edit_multiple` which takes a list of id's a such:

```
def edit_multiple
  @products = Product.find(params[:product_ids])
end
```

and a routes.rb:

```
resources: products do
  collection do
    post :edit_multiple
  end
end
```

and a collection of products in a `products` variable in a view which I want to pass as the arguments to a path in a `link_to` something like:

```
<%= link_to edit_multiple_products_path(:product_ids => products), :method => :post do %>
  update products
<% end %>
```

when I click the link i get the error:

```
Couldn't find Product with id=#<ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_Product:0x495c900>
```

Please note I'm using Rails 4

Comment: use Product.where(" id in =?", params[:product_ids])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also change your view from:

```
<%= link_to edit_multiple_products_path(:product_ids => products), :method => :post do %>
  update products
<% end %>
```

to:

```
<%= link_to edit_multiple_products_path(:product_ids => products.map(&:id)), :method => :post do %>
  update products
<% end %>
```

and you will get an products ids array..

Answer (score 2):

If product ids are coming as an array use `where`, not `find`:

```
@products = Product.where("id in (?)", params[:product_ids])
```

Comment: `find` expects to receive, as an argument, a single id and then return a single product. Using `where` will allow you to send multiple ids and receive back multiple products.